# 33 * 33 bit using 16 bit DSPs

Tags: vhdl, verilog, multiplication

I want to write a vhdl/verilog code to multiply 2 33 vector using 16 bit dsps.

I really don't understand the mechanism of splitting the 2 33 vector into smaller vectors. Then use multiply and addition to get the final result.
Could anyone please explain how to do so.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for telling me why. To be honest I tried but all what I found is how to make a decimal like binary multiplication. I will try to re-edit the post to explain more clearly the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do that.

Just instance a 33x33 multiplier and the FPGA mapping tools will take care of splitting and recombination.

If you insist of doing it yourself look up "Wallace tree multiplier". That is the principle of how multipliers are build in hardware, with the improvement of using carry look ahead adders.

Comment: Thank you I was looking an algorithm explaining this. I wanted to do it my self the idea is to learn, it's easy to let the mapping tools do everything. The problem is that we will not understand what is going on beneath it.